# Call webservice from visualsource flow

Tags: webservices

How do I call a webservice (using client provided wsdl) and call its functions from withing a salesforce application (flow)?

Comment: Are you referring to visual workflow ? or apex ? Please understand that questions are easier to answer when it's clear you've already done some research, include more details and are able to focus your question on a specific aspect rather than a general information request.

Comment: Yes as Samuel De Rycke says above, if you clarify your question you will get more accurate responses. Flow can mean multiple things. Workflow Rules? Visual Flow? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a sample example from blog link

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2014/09/invoking-apex-callouts-through-visual.html

I have clearly documented each step .As mentioned you will need to implement Process plugin

```
global class WeatherApp implements Process.Plugin { 

// The main method to be implemented. The Flow calls this at runtime.
global Process.PluginResult invoke(Process.PluginRequest request) { 
    // Get the State and City From Flow
    String State = (String) request.inputParameters.get('state');
    String City = (String) request.inputParameters.get('city');

    // Use the API to call and fetch Weather Info
     WeatherInfo weatherinformation=new WeatherInfo();

    // Instantiate a new http object
     Http h = new Http();

    // Instantiate a new HTTP request, specify the method (GET) as well as the endpoint
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     String requestURL='http://api.wunderground.com/api/551013da52923e43/conditions/q/';//One needs to generate the API Key From the http://api.wunderground.com
     requestURL=requestURL+state+'/'+city+'.json';
     req.setEndpoint(requestURL);
     req.setMethod('GET');

    // Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    weatherinformation=(WeatherInfo)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), WeatherInfo.class);

    // return to Flow
    Map<String,Object> result = new Map<String,Object>();
    result.put('temperature',weatherinformation.Current_observation.temp_c); 
    result.put('faherneit',weatherinformation.Current_observation.temp_f);
    result.put('dewpoint_f',weatherinformation.Current_observation.dewpoint_f);
    return new Process.PluginResult(result); 
} 

// Returns the describe information for the interface
global Process.PluginDescribeResult describe() { 
    Process.PluginDescribeResult result = new Process.PluginDescribeResult(); 
    result.Name = 'weatherappplugin';
    result.Tag = 'weatherapp';
    result.inputParameters = new 
       List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter>{ 
           new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('state', 
           Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, true) ,
           new Process.PluginDescribeResult.InputParameter('city', 
           Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.STRING, true) 
        }; 
    result.outputParameters = new 
       List<Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter>{
        // Temperature obtained From The webservice
        new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter(
            'temperature', 
            Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.Double),
         new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter(
            'faherneit', 
            Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.Double),
         new Process.PluginDescribeResult.OutputParameter(
            'dewpoint_f', 
            Process.PluginDescribeResult.ParameterType.Integer)
       }; 
    return result; 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Visual Flow.

1. Using Apex2WSDL you can generate the client stub classes. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm
2. Create an Apex Class that implements Process.Plugin. (http://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf) Page 17, 19
3. Inside your Apex Class call the Web Service via the client apex classes, and return the results to the calling Visual Flow.